# change submit value in render dependant on if it's #new or #edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Doing a bit of cleaning up in my code, trying to make it as DRY as possible. One of the problems that have arisen whilst doing so is that they are the same on both  the #new and #edit. Taking for example the submit button.

I would like the text on the submmt #new to be "create your profile" whilst on #edit to be "update your profile".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object#persisted?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) for identifying if the record exists on db. So, you could put the next code on the related rails helper (app/helpers) in order to avoid get logic on views:

```
def title
    @comment.persisted? ? "Update your profile" : "Create your profile"
end
```

Cheers!